# How long does a wormhole file transfer persist

Tags: file-transfer, mmwormhole

I am trying to use [magic-wormhole](https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to receive a file.

My partner and I are in different time zones, however.

If my partner types `wormhole send filename`, for how long will this file persist (i.e. how much later can I type `wormhole receive keyword` and still get the file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the "Timing" section in the docs](https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/welcome.html#timing):

> The program does not have any built-in timeouts, however it is expected that both clients will be run within an hour or so of each other ... Both clients must be left running until the transfer has finished.

So... maybe? Consider using some cloud storage instead, depending on the file. You could also encrypt it before uploading it to cloud storage if the contents of the file is private.